# How to set priority of the backgroundLoading of an Image in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, background-process

I thought this would be a simple find but I’ve been struggling to find something simple that does what I’m looking for and I’ve been stuck on it for a few days. Basically, I have a ListView which displays loads of images, however the images load from top to bottom and the lower images wont load before the top ones have finished.

For obvious performance reasons I’ve set the backgroundLoading priority to true:

```
Image image = new Image(url, true);
```

And this does alot for what I want, however the fact it only loads from top to bottom has presented me with two problems:

1. When my user scrolls far down in the list, I want to create an event which sets the on screen images to load immediately, I don’t want it to wait for the images super far above images to load first, so I’m hoping I can find a way to simply load these images (which are already in the loading queue mind that) before the ones above, and then when it’s done it keeps loading the images above.
2. When my user clicks the image, it opens a panel which displays another image loaded from a new link retrieved when clicked, and alike above, these image won’t load until all the others have loaded. So I would like to set the priority of this loading image to top priority.

Solutions I have come up with:

- One is creating the image without background loading, but I do not wish to do this since it freezes my whole program until the image loads.
- Another is to use Image.cancel() on all of my images to stop the loading, and then load the new images, and then set all the cancelled image back to load. But I felt this was inefficient but if there’s no better way I’ll think more on this idea.

**TL;DR How do I load an image in the background before other images currently being loading the background. Thanks.**

Comment: One possible solution: Create a queue of some sort that runs in another thread (For example a List of Objects that contain the images location and associated component) and update/display the images as they are loaded. On first starting or showing the window you can add all relevant images to the queue initially and let it load them, but as the user scrolls you can simply remove any unloaded images that have moved out of view and add others to the front of the queue as they move into view. You will need to write a bit of logic for this to track the scrolling etc, but it is quite dooable.

Comment: That does sounds good, I already have some stuff in place for events to get items on scroll. However I'm not very familiar with threads. I'd greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right place to look up how to use them for what I need. I tried look into it already but I got a bit confused.

Comment: _I'm not very familiar with threads_ then do some research to find appropriate tutorials, work through them, apply to your context, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's wrong. And make sure to read the how-to-ask help pages to understand which type of questions are on-scope here (asking to find resources definitely is not ;)

Comment: Maybe try to call [`cancel()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#cancel()) on images that you started loading but don't need. You may need to worry about rapid scrolling and then reversing scroll direction.

Comment: I would probably use your second solution. If a cell goes out of view, then cancel the load; that way resources are freed up to load other images that are actually visible. You may also want to implement some sort of memory-constrained cache which holds already-loaded images.